# In PowerShell, how to I send mail and enumerate in email body list of discovered errors

Tags: powershell, sendmail

I have the following code snippet from my PowerShell script that...

- Loops through a list of servers
- Does a Select-String -notmatch on the error log at each server
- Flags the server if the error log is bad, and gives the OK if the error log if fine

What I'd like to also do is send an email report that enumerates each of the discovered bad error logs in a list, and also list all the servers whose error logs are OK. Something like this in the email body:

The following servers have bad error logs:

- Server3
- Server6
- Server14

The following servers are OK:

- Server1
- Server2
- Server5

Here is my code snippet:

```
$Servers = Get-Content $ServerLst
ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
{
   $ErrorLog = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$Server\$LOG_PATH -Include Error.log -Recurse | Select-String -notmatch $SEARCH_STR
   If ($ErrorLog)
   {
    Write-Host "Bad Error Log found at $Server!"
   }
   Else
   {
    Write-Host "Error log is OK."           
   }
}
```

I'm guessing I would need a Send-Mail function where I would pass in the server names with bad error logs, etc. However, I'm not quite sure how to approach this.

Any great ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Powershell V1 use [this function](http://poshcode.org/2217) from the Powershell Cookbook to send mail. In Powershell V2 you can send mail using [Send-MailMessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347693.aspx).

```
$Servers = Get-Content $ServerLst
$Bad = "The following servers have bad error logs:`n`n"
$OK = "`nThe following servers are OK:`n`n"
ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
{
   $ErrorLog = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$Server\$LOG_PATH -Include Error.log -Recurse | Select-String -notmatch $SEARCH_STR
   If ($ErrorLog)
   {
    $Bad += "`t - $Server`n"
   }
   Else
   {
    $OK += "`t - $Server`n"           
   }
}
Send-MailMessage -Body "$Bad $OK" -Subject "Bad Logs" -SmtpServer $servername -To $to -From $from
```

**Remark:** The smtpserver parameter is called smtphost in the Powershell cookbook function.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a clean approach. I will give it a try when I return to work.

Comment: Hi Jon Z, just to follow up...I've tried your solution and it works great so far! Thanks again!!

Comment: Another question. I want to take this a step further and specify the numbers of servers that have bad error logs and the number of servers that are OK. So $Bad would be something like "The following _n_ servers that have bad error logs:". And $OK would be.."The following _n_ servers are OK:". How would I do this? I think I would need to do a count but not sure where to do the count.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make the function on your own, but here is some pseudo code:

```
Function SendMail
{
    Param(...your params here)

    ...send the mail...


}

<...

Your code to check all your servers

You need to save your errors or issues to an array or hashtable.  
I'll assume you use a 2-field array called $ErrArray

...>

# Now at the end you build a string for the body of the email to incorporate your errors

$StrBody = "Bad Error Log Report`n`n"

$ErrArray | ForEach-Object {$StrBody = $Strbody + "`n$($_[0]) server had an issue: $($_[1])`n"}

SendMail $EmailTo $EmailSubject $StrBody
```

So the breakdown:

- Make a mail function
- Save the results of your analysis to an array or hashtable
- Iterate through your results object and append each result record to the string for your email
- Call the email function

Comment: Hi JNK, thanks for the feedback! I was thinking of almost the exact same thing you described above. Just wanted to get an expert's opinion. I'll give your approach a try and post back later...

Comment: I've used this in some larger scripts where I send exception reports for when  things don't process correctly and it works great.  You should also make sure to use appropriate error trapping to a log file since email procedures can (and often do) fail because of issues outside your script.